# Downloading Transparent PNG's on Android using Appcelerator turns the background black

Tags: android, titanium, png, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Can anyone shed any light on why, using the [Image Factory module](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.imagefactory) to download and store images on Android, does it ignore the transparency on PNG graphics and give them a black background?

It works fine on iOS and everything is "as is".

Do I need to add anything to the download script to retain the transparency?

Help!

Here is my download script, I'm building using Titanium 3.5.1 GA:

```
function getMarker(url, filename) {

// this will enable us to have multiple file sizes per device
var filename2 = filename.replace(".png", "@2x.png");
var filename3 = filename.replace(".png", "@3x.png");

var mapMarker = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'map_marker_icons', filename);
var mapMarker2 = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'map_marker_icons', filename2);
var mapMarker3 = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'map_marker_icons', filename3);

// now we need to download the map marker and save it into our device 

var getMarker = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    timeout: 30000
});

getMarker.onload = function() {

    // if the file loads, then write to the filesystem
    if (getMarker.status == 200) {
        // resize the images into non-retina, retina and retina HD and only download and resize what is actyally required

            var getOriginal = ImageFactory.imageWithAlpha(this.responseData, {});

            var resized2 = ImageFactory.imageAsResized(getOriginal, {
                width: 50,
                height: 50
            });
            mapMarker.write(resized2);
            Ti.API.info(filename + " Image resized");


        //I ALWAYS NULL ANY PROXIES CREATED SO THAT IT CAN BE RELEASED
        mapMarker = null;
    } else {
        Ti.API.info("Image not loaded");
    }

    // load the tours in next
    loadNav();



};

getMarker.onerror = function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('XHR Error ' + e.error);
    //alert('markers data error');
};

getMarker.ondatastream = function(e) {
    //Ti.API.info('Download progress: ' + e.progress);
};

// open the client
getMarker.open('GET', url);

// change the loading message
MainActInd.message = 'Downloading Markers';
// show the indicator
MainActInd.show();

// send the data
getMarker.send();    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Simon

Comment: If you would save `getOriginal`, does it have the change too?

Comment: Yeah, i tried that as well, no joy, forgot I left that in there, but yes it still downloads with a black background

Comment: Then do not use ImageFactory to download a file. I do not know titanium but there should be something to direct the responseData directly to a file/outputstream i hope for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code, I tried it on Android and iOS with a png Url, first I GET the photo with HTTP client request, then I save it as a file with extension png and then I read it with an `ImageView`.

index.js:

```
$.win.open();

savePng("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-set/29/Soundcloud-128.png");
function savePng(pngUrl) {
    var client = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {
            var image_file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "test.png");
            image_file.write(this.responseData);
            $.img.image = image_file.read();
        },
        onerror : function(e) {
            alert(e.error);
        },
        timeout : 10000
    });
    client.open("GET", pngUrl);
    client.send();
}
```

index.xml:

```
<Alloy>
        <Window id="win" backgroundColor="gray">
        <ImageView id="img" />
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: These particular images are used for map markers, so I can't use image views to display them. I'll see if not using image factory though in the original download, like your snippet, will do the job, then i can do the resize later on.

Comment: OK, saving it like your suggestion works, no black background! Just need to resize the images now, hoping that will be easy.

Comment: You don't have to use image views, I am just proving that they don't have a black background..

Comment: Try this code for resizing `resizedImage = image.imageAsResized(200, 300);`, try it on `this.responseData` which is the image, and let me know if it didn't work.